# Stop a for loop when user is finished entering input in c

Tags: c, arrays, loops, for-loop

First of all, thank you for the assist!

I'm new to the C language (and programming in general) and I'm trying to write a program wherein the user inputs data points. The data points are then saved in an array where they can then be manipulated.

Where I am stuck: I want the user to be able to input (almost) any number of points, then use a 'keyword' of sorts to signal the end of data entry. In this case, the user would type 'done'.

Here's what I have so far:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(void) {

printf("\n Welcome! \n\n Please enter each data point. Enter 'done' when finished.\n\n");

double data[1048];
int i, count;

for (i = 1; ;i++) {

    printf("Data[%i]: ", i);
    scanf("%lf", &data[i]);

    if (data[i] == 'done') {

        break;

    } else {

        count++;

    }

  } 

}
```

I've tried 'return 1;' and 'break;'. Each time, the program works well until the 'keyword' is entered, at which point I get:

```
Data[8]: Data[9]: ... Data[1120]: Data[1Segmentation fault 11
```

The only time it works is if I have it break when the user inputs a particular number (like -1 or 0). But that doesn't quite work for the user since they might have to enter those numbers as data points.

Sorry for the long post, but I appreciate the help!

Comment: The data type for data is double   double data[1048]; and you are equating it with char values. That's a type error. If you want to equate, use long, instead of double. Double is a floating point type.

Comment: Okey, okey. How this was compiled ?

Comment: `'` is for type `char` values, which is just a single character. It doesn't make sense to write `'done'`, that's a string.

Comment: @Barmar character constants have type `int` in C

Comment: Arrays are `zero based` in C, (e.g. `Data[0], Data[1], ... Data[1047]` in your case). At minimum, your loop needs to be `for (i = 0; i < 1048; i++)` (although there are better ways to keep track of array indexes)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have received a number of good answers to your question, and there are several more ways to take input of `doubles` and stop on `"done"`. Since you are learning C, always, ***ALWAYS*** (in case it wasn't clear), *check the return of* `scanf` to validate the number of *conversions* you expected actually took place.***[1]*** (this also provides your way to end input on `"done"` (or any non-double entered causing `scanf` to return less than `1`)

As noted in the comment, arrays are ***zero based*** in C. When you are taking input, you will want to use `count` as your array-index, rather than `i` (in this case if you exit the read on each failure -- it doesn't matter, but you could just as easily prompt again for additional input and increment `count` only on a successful return from `scanf`) Back to your question. If you set up your read loop to continually loop until there is a `scanf` failure, you can make use of a temporary variable to initially capture the input value, and only assign the value to your array and increment your index on success. e.g. (with a constant `MAXD = 1048`)

```
for (;;) {  /* loop until scanf input fails (with 'done') */

    double tmp;  /* block scope declarations are fine */

    printf (" data[%4d]: ", count);

    if (count < MAXD && scanf(" %lf", &tmp) == 1)
        data[count++] = tmp;
    else
        break;
}
```

(you can even move a copy of the prompt above the loop, and move the one above after the `if (....) {...}` to eliminate the prompt when the array limit (`MAXD`) is reached -- that's left as an exercise)

In the example above you have 2 conditions you enforce before storing a value. (1) you limit the number of values your user can store to `MAXD`, and (2) you only store a value if a valid conversion to `double` takes place in `scanf`. You leave the loop if either of the conditions fails (which if you enter `"done"` as a double-value, it will).

Putting the pieces together and dropping a few additional tips in the comments, you could test with something like the following:

```
#include <stdio.h>

enum { MAXD = 1048 };   /* declare constants instead of using magic numbers */

int main (void) {

    double data[MAXD] = {0};    /* in ISO C declarations come before code */
    int i, count = 0;           /* initializing variable saves debug time */

    printf ("\n Welcome! \n\n Please enter each data point. "
            "Enter 'done' when finished.\n\n");

    for (;;) {  /* loop until scanf input fails (with 'done') */

        double tmp;  /* block scope declarations are fine */

        printf (" data[%4d]: ", count);

        if (count < MAXD && scanf(" %lf", &tmp) == 1)
            data[count++] = tmp;
        else
            break;
    } 

    printf ("\n %d values entered:\n\n", count);

    for (i = 0; i < count; i++)
        printf ("  data[%4d] : %.2lf\n", i, data[i]);

    return 0;   /* main() is type 'int' and returns a value */
}
```

**Example Use/Output**

```
$ ./bin/scanfdoubles

 Welcome!

 Please enter each data point. Enter 'done' when finished.

 data[   0]: 1.1
 data[   1]: 1.2
 data[   2]: 1.3
 data[   3]: 1.4
 data[   4]: 1.5
 data[   5]: 1.6
 data[   6]: done

 6 values entered:

  data[   0] : 1.10
  data[   1] : 1.20
  data[   2] : 1.30
  data[   3] : 1.40
  data[   4] : 1.50
  data[   5] : 1.60
```

Look things over and let me know if you have any questions.

***footnotes:***

***1.*** while you *can* use `scanf` to take user-input in C, you are better off using a *line-oriented* function (like `fgets`) and then parsing the complete line (with, e.g. `sscanf`). The allows you to both (1) validate the read (e.g. the return of `fgets`) and then (2) separately validate the value entered by the user. This ***decoupling*** of your read, and your parsing has many advantages.

Comment: Wow! Great answer. Thank you very much! 

I am currently working my way through _Programming in C, 4th ed._ by Stephen Kochan and all he's really covered so far is `scanf` so I'll have to do some more research on the technique(s) you mention in your footnote.

And just to paraphrase so I understand: `scanf` returns a `0` if unsuccessful, `1` if successful. So, I can check for success by checking for a `1` [as in `scanf(" %lf", &tmp) == 1`]. If `0`, then my loop stops.

Comment: No, all of the `scanf` family of functions (`scanf`, `sscanf`, etc..) return the ***match count*** which is the number of *successful conversions* that take place according to ***format-specifiers*** contained in the ***format string***. (e.g. the *format-string* `" %lf"` contains one *format-specifier* `%lf` for conversion to `double`. Therefore, a return of `1` would indicate success, anything else failure, and `EOF` (generally `-1`) would indicate end of file reached. Glad the answer helped, C is a fantastic language, it takes time to learn, so slow-down, enjoy the ride.

Comment: As part of the learning process, one invaluable tool are the *man pages*. They explain each function in mind numbing detail. They look cryptic as hell when you first look at them, but do, and take the time to let what they are telling you sink in. After a while, it will be second nature to fire off `man scanf` (or get the page on the web) and have all the information you need at a glance.

Comment: When I checked what ISO considers to be ISO C by [searching their site](https://www.iso.org/search/x/query/C%2520programming/refine/more:standard) I found that they no longer consider C99 to be ISO C; that support has been withdrawn in favour of C11, it seems. C89 hasn't been considered ISO C by ISO for a long time, and since ISO decides what ISO C is, well... gotta go with what they say, eh... The requirement that declarations within blocks precede logic was, of course, rendered obsolete by C99. FWIW, ansi.org has a similar search engine which yields similar results.

Comment: That's good info. The only fly-in-the-ointment is we still get a lot of posts from folks building on Win7 with VS (`cl.exe`). That version only supports C89 (mind boggling, but yes Windows 7 `cl.exe` -- still uses a nearly 30 year old compiler standard. So in a lot of cases, if I can't discern the OS, I try and make the code compatible with a broad collection of current OS's. (funny -- how publicly funded institution like ASNI that we pay for already wants us to pay again to get a copy of whatever standard we may be in need of....`:)`

Answer (score 1):

No element of data[] will ever be 'done' (they're floats).  If you want to scanf() directly, you'll need to choose a double value that ends the sequence (commonly zero or -1 or something).  If that won't work, you can either use something like:

1. Use fgets() to pull a string, then strncmp() to check for the terminating value and sscanf() to pull out the double, or:
2. Have the user use Ctrl-D to terminate and check the scan value for EOF.

Oh, and strictly speaking you have an upper limit of entries.  You should check i to make sure that you don't exceed that.  Never assume your input won't exceed boundaries.  sizeof() on a statically-allocated variable or some #defined macro to track that.

Comment: `gets()` is obsolete, use `fgets()`.

Comment: Too right.  I've been a C programmer a long time :-). Answer updated.

Answer (score 0):

- Your `data` is of type `double`. It can't scan a literal "done".

Instead use `EOF` for checking end of input.

```
while(scanf("%lf",&data[i]) != EOF) {
    ...
}
```

Another way:

```
while(scanf("%lf",&data[i]) == 1) {
    ...
}
```

- Another thing, initialize count to zero, i.e. `count = 0;`

Comment: The first way is bad, it will not detect if the person types "done"

Comment: If it even were the string literal `"done"`, as it stands its a multibyte character `'done'`.

Comment: That's why I suggested to use EOF rather than using literals for checking end of input.

Answer (score 0):

Bottom line: don't use `scanf`.

Use something like

```
char inputline[100];

i = 0;

while(fgets(inputline, sizeof(inputline), stdin) != NULL) {
    if(strncmp(inputline, "done", 4) == 0) break;
    data[i++] = atof(inputline);
}
```

`scanf` is hard enough to use even when all your inputs are the numbers you expect.  If the input might be either a number or the word "done", `scanf` will never work.  But reading a line of text, as here, is generally easier and more flexible.

P.S. You also have to worry about the possibility that the user enters more than 1048 numbers.

Comment: What do you think of the situation where `sizeof(inputline) - 1` characters are read from `stdin`, none of them are newlines and so `fgets` reads no further, leaving `stdin` in an inconsistent state for the next loop iteration?

Comment: Also, you write *"If the input might be either a number or the word "done", `scanf` will never work."* but I think it can, and does work here, in this very question. Replace OPs loop-enclosed logic with this, for example: `if (scanf("%lf", &data[i]) == 1) { count++; continue; } char e; if (feof(stdin) || ferror(stdin) || (scanf("don%c", &e) == 1 && e == 'e')) { break; }` ... I'll leave it as a challenge for you to come up with something so elegantly expressed and yet robust without using `scanf`.

Answer (score 0):

For your task the loop of gathering input should control not only keyword, but also number if inputs. I suggest to do this as follows:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#define NUM_OF_DATA 1048

int main(void) 
{
    printf("\n Welcome! \n\n Please enter each data point. Enter 'done' when finished.\n\n");
    double data[NUM_OF_DATA];
    int i; // counter of entered numbers
    char str[5] = { 0 }; // string to read 'done' or other word from input
    for (i = 0; i < NUM_OF_DATA; i++) // the first index of data in array is 0 (the last NUM_OF_DATA-1)
    {
        printf("Data[%i]: ", i);
        if (1 == scanf("%lf", &data[i])) // if number was successfully read
            continue; // go to next iteration
        // if some problem was with reading a loat number
        // read the string
        scanf("%4s", str); // read not more than 4 characters from input
        if ( strcmp(str, "done") == 0) 
        {
            break; // stop input if 'done' was entered
        }
        // clean input buffer before next input
        while (getchar() != '\n');
        // correct counter in case of wrong input
        i--;
    }
    // output the number of correct inputs
    printf("%d numbers were entered.\n", i);
    // do something with data
    // taking in account, that i is not index of the last element, 
    // but the number of elements (indexes are 0 ... i-1)
    // ...
    return 0;
}
```

This `for` loop stops in two cases:

1) when `data` array is full,

2) when `'done'` without quotes entered.

Additional feature is skipping of incorrect input (try how it works).