# Missing value with scanf in C89

Tags: c, scanf

Hope you guys can help me with a problem I'm having.

So I have this C code snippet:

```
int i = 0;
int q = 0;

scanf("%d %d", &i, &q);
```

When the user enters `4 5`, the values 4 and 5 are stored in i and q respectively.

But when the user enters `99.99`, 99 is stored in i, but the other 99 after the point goes missing. I do know how scanf works and I understand that scanf will stop scanning after `.`, but where does the second value go to?

Even if I do:

```
int i = 0;
int q = 0;
int k = 0;


scanf("%d %d", &i, &q);
scanf("%d", &k);
```

I still cant get the second value. Where does the second value go and how can I get store it in my variable?

Comment: correct, but i would like to store 99.99 as 2 int values instead of a single float value, 99 and 99, which is why i want the second value

Comment: @xing but why does my value not get stored when i did ".%d" in the second scanf call? It should match the pending input stream, right?

Comment: You need to check the return value from `scanf()`.  When debugging, capture it in a variable and print it as well as test it. It will tell you about what’s going on. When you get 1 and not 2, you know you’ve got a problem.

Answer (score 0):

It is trying to look for integer but it is not integer that is left in `stdin` so it fails.

You can get desired behavior if you do this

```
int a,b;
scanf("%d.%d",&a,&b);
printf("%d,%d",a,b);
```

This prints `99,99` as expected.

For your information,

- `scanf` stops at the first mismatch and leaves the rest of the target objects untouched.
- Also the unmatched data is left in the input buffer, available for a subsequent read using `scanf` etc.
- Also  you can check the return value to determine how many "items" scanf matched.

Answer (score 0):

`scanf()` doesn't ignore the `.` while expects to read an `int`. I suggest you use [`fgets()`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/fgetc.3.html) and then try to parse with `sscanf()` which is a better approach. Something like:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void)
{
   int i = 0;
   int q = 0;
   char line[256];

   if (fgets(line, sizeof line, stdin)) {
      if (sscanf(line, "%d.%d", &i, &q) == 2) {
         printf("i=%d, j=%d\n", i, q);
      } else {
         printf("Coudn't scan 2 ints\n");
      }
   } else {
      printf("Couldn't read a line\n");
   }   
}
```

Note that `fgets()` will also read in the newline character if there's space in the buffer. It doesn't matter in this case.
But you need to be aware of it and may be undesirable in some cases (e.g., reading a *name*).

Also see: [Why does everyone say not to use scanf? What should I use instead?](http://c-faq.com/stdio/scanfprobs.html)

Comment: *Better*? That's your opinion; the article you linked to doesn't say that, and neither does the Torek explanation nor the Summit explanation. What those reputable experts realise is that like many tools in C, `scanf` can easily be abused with bad consequences. **You can't make the argument that one shouldn't use `scanf` and then make the argument that everything else in C is perfectly fine and dandy**, right? By your logic, perhaps we should just **stop using C**.

Comment: When more than 256 characters are entered, your `fgets`-abusing code fails to correct the stream just like the `scanf` code... Not to worry, because the simplest way to correct that issue is using `scanf`... You need something like: `if (!line[strcspn(line, "\n")]) { scanf("%*[^\n]"); scanf("%*c"); }`. The only alternatives to that line of code introduce unnecessary variables, just like your intermediate variable `line`.

Comment: Nobody claimed C is flawless; what anyone says about `scanf` is that it's *hard* to use it *correctly*. While `fgets()` provides a *better* control over error checking (such as invalid inputs). Suggesting to *avoid* scanf doesn't imply either "then make the argument that everything else in C is perfectly fine" or " stop using C" in anyway.

Comment: It's not *hard* to use them correctly... at least, no harder than it is to use *arrays* correctly, or to avoid *race conditions* correctly. Once you're aware of the pattern, it'll become habit. This is a strength for us programmers; we're very good at establishing idioms which may seem counterintuitive to beginners, but serve perfectly rational explanations.

Comment: As I've demonstrated, `fgets` is just as easy to abuse. Another commonly established *easy-to-abuse* feature is `goto`, and for all of its criticism there are perfectly valid usecases for which it is the most appropriate tool... **You should always use the most appropriate tool**, and based on this answer, I don't think that's the mentality you carry.

Comment: You have some strong opinions that I don't agree. No, you haven't demonstrated "fgets() is easy to abuse". You have demonstrated fgets() has problems. "fgets is better" != "fgets is perfect"; all that's implied here is "it's easier to use scanf and get it wrong" than with fgets. [Steve summit himself has said this before](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39071701/4389800).

Comment: I've demonstrated that **`fgets` has precisely the same problem as `scanf`**; it leaves the tail of a line of input behind when it fails to read a complete line. In your code, everything from the 255th byte of the line onwards up until a newline will be remaining in `stdin`, rendering any future calls to read functions *dirty*. How are you going to fix that? The same way you would if you used `scanf`... Do you know the difference? Your code introduces an unnecessary temporary variable and a call to `fgets`... That's the difference.

Comment: There's no *opinion* about what I'm explaining. I'm not arguing that `scanf` is *better* than `fgets`. I'm arguing that it has usecases where it's more appropriate, where using `scanf` instead of `fgets` and `sscanf` will lead to *cleaner and easier to maintain code*. Similarly, `fgets` has usecases where it's more appropriate than `scanf`. Until a usecase is specified, one should not choose either option. The information in the question is insufficient to suggest that one tool is more appropriate than the other, rendering your use of the word "*better*" as an *opinion*.

Comment: "**You have demonstrated fgets() has problems. "fgets is better" != "fgets is perfect"; all that's implied here is "it's easier to use scanf and get it wrong" than with fgets**".

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/157741/discussion-between-sebivor-and-usr).

Answer (score 0):

Let X be the following statement...

> I do know how scanf works

Let Y be the following statement...

> ... but where does the second value go to?

X and Y do not correspond. Either you know about the return value of `scanf`, or you don't know how `scanf` works. That's the bottom line.

---

> ... but where does the second value go to?

According to [the `fscanf` manual](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/fscanf.html),

> The fscanf() functions shall execute each directive of the format in turn. If a directive fails, as detailed below, the function shall return. Failures are described as input failures (due to the unavailability of input bytes) or matching failures (due to inappropriate input).

The space directive won't match the `.` input, which will cause a matching failure, `scanf` will return, meaning that nothing beyond the `.` byte will be *consumed* from `stdin`. In fact, `scanf` will even put the `.` *back into* `stdin` for you, just before it returns... *Isn't that nice?*

I gather you understand this (because you said "I do know how `scanf` works"), yet you seem to be asking about that second *value* which couldn't have been read due to a previous matching failure... thus, the answer to your first question is, *the second value doesn't exist*. It can't exist yet, because an input format error exists prior to it.

While we're on the topic of `scanf`, return values and matching failures, for the remaining question I'm going to assume your code actually looks something more like this:

```
int i = 0;
int q = 0;
if (scanf("%d %d", &i, &q) != 2) {
    puts("Discarding invalid input");
    scanf("%*[^\n]");      // discard up to the next newline and...
    getchar();             // discard that newline, too.
                           // XXX: You might want to `return` or `continue` or something
}
```

---

> ... and how can I get store it in my variable?

As mentioned earlier, the space directive doesn't match the period. You need to replace that with something which manipulates the input stream as you intend... That's difficult for me to answer, because I don't have that information, but here's what I'd suggest: Split the two *conversions* up into two separate calls to `scanf`. This should give you a nice place in between the two calls to `scanf` to insert your *period-handling* code.

Here's a before & after, side-by-side, of the idiom I've adopted for that kind of input:

```
// BEFORE                              // AFTER
if (scanf("%d %d", &i, &q) != 2) {     if (scanf("%d", &i) != 1) {
// ...                                     puts("Invalid first input...");
                                           // XXX: Handle this???
                                           // XXX: `return` or `continue` or something
                                       }
                                       // XXX: Read a character, check if it's a space (or a dot, or something else which you have in your mind and I don't have in mine)
                                       if (scanf("%d", &q) != 1) {
                                           // ...
```

Handling the erroneous period could be as simple as exiting the process or calling `getchar()` to discard a single character, then `continue`ing in order to *try again*. These solutions won't solve *all* user input errors, and might even confuse or frustrate some users. I recommend sticking with the *discard the rest of the line* method, at least until you learn about *all of the alternatives* for user input and what they're each best at. After all, people tend to avoid using software which confuses them...

... hence the reason people tend to discourage `scanf`... because I guess  *there's no such thing as literature which sets a standard*, and thus *there's no way to correct my `scanf`-related misunderstandings*.